# Where should I declare state variables using Hooks in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-state

I just started using Hooks and I don't know where should I set the initial values of the state variables?
For example when we use Class Components we set state in the Constructer

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state{
    test : ''
  }
}
```

..so what is the equivalent in Hooks?

**P.S: I do know how to set state and update state in Hooks :**

```
 const [refreshOrders, setRefreshOrders] = useState(false);
 setRefreshOrders(true);
```

**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: Typically with `hooks` you wouldn't be using them with a class anyways. If you want to start using using `hooks` try to use them with functional components. I think you'll find them simpler to use in that fashion.

Comment: what is your question? because you asked "set the initial values of the state" and then you have answered to your question in P.S. so what is your question?

Comment: @SagharMirali initially where should these be set? You can use this `setRefreshOrders(true)` to set it anywhere but initially they  have to be set somewhere (before the component has been mounted such as Constructor in Classes).

Comment: function App(){                                                                                                             
         const [refreshOrders, setRefreshOrders] = useState("here is initial value");                                                             
         return ( ... )}

Answer (score 0):

```
function Example() {
    const initialState = {}
    const [refreshOrders, setRefreshOrders] = useState(initialState);
```

if you want to change the value

```
function Example() {
changeState=()=>{

    setRefreshOrders({...initialState, name:'newValue'});
}
```

Comment: And where do you place this (such as Constructor in Classes)?

Comment: For normal you'll define it at the top of your functional component, so you can use it afterwards

Comment: I did but then I want to change the state in another function but it doesnt seem to work that way!

Comment: Please try to understand my question!